# how to abort shutdown command in ubuntu?

Tags: shutdown

If I give this command for shutting down the system:

```
$ sudo shutdown -h 10:20 "going down"
```

how can I abort it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As we can read from manual page `man shutdown`

> ```
>    -c
>        Cancel a pending shutdown. This may be used cancel the effect of an
>        invocation of shutdown with a time argument that is not "+0" or "now".
> ```

Comment: Great that it is in the manual, but I had only 1 minute to google this answer, and I'm very glad I found it in time. I probably wouldn't have found it if I had to look in the manual.